# opening the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file

I would like to write a console program that reads the contents from a file (.txt).
However, I have a problem after selecting "2" from the menu (load from file). I get an error that I can not deal with.

```py
def open(args):
    path = 'C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/python/crc/crc2/demofile.txt'
    plik = open(path,'r')
    content = plik.read()
    print(content)

def menu(args):
    print("MENU \n")
    print("1: Ciąg CRC podany z klawiatury \n2: Ciąg CRC wczytany z pliku")

    m = input()
    arg2 = 0
    if m=='1':
        cal(args)
    elif m =='2':
        open(args)
    else:
        print("Podaj poprawną wartość !!!")
        menu(args)
    return 0
```

ERROR:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
open() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\python\crc\crc2\crc.py", line 8, in open
    plik = open(path,'r')
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\python\crc\crc2\crc.py", line 37, in menu
    open(args)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\python\crc\crc2\crc.py", line 48, in main
    menu(args)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\python\crc\crc2\crc.py", line 55, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you redefined `open`, so calling `open` is like calling your custom function. Instead, import the `builtins` module to avoid name-mangling:

```
import builtins

def open(args):
    path = 'C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/python/crc/crc2/demofile.txt'
    plik = builtins.open(path,'r') # Calling the built-in open instead of your function
    content = plik.read()
    print(content)

def menu(args):
    print("MENU \n")
    print("1: Ciąg CRC podany z klawiatury \n2: Ciąg CRC wczytany z pliku")

    m = input()
    arg2 = 0
    if m=='1':
        cal(args)
    elif m =='2':
        open(args)
    else:
        print("Podaj poprawną wartość !!!")
        menu(args)
    return 0
```

Comment: @TomB If you found my answer helpful, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.